# Align image captions, images and tiles when images are of different height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement tiles for prices including div container, image and caption. The problem is that images are of different sizes (and shouldn't be resized) so I cannot get everything aligned

Tried to add `vertical-align` to image (`baseline`) and caption (`top`) but the tiles are still not aligned in this case. Here is the example:
[Tiles are not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9A4E.png)

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tile-topup tile-blue">
        <img src="coin-1.png">
        <h4>1$</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-topup tile-green">
        <img src="coin-2.png">
        <h4>2$</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-topup tile-purple">
        <img src="coin-3.png">
        <h4>3$</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-topup tile-red">
        <img src="coin-4.png">
        <h4>4$</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tile-topup {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Images, text and tiles should ve vertically aligned. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```css
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

Change 'display: inline-block' to 'display: block'
This will make it so that every image starts out on a new line beneath the previous one.
Then set 'margin-left: auto' and 'margin-right: auto'
This adds enough margin on either side of the boxes to centre your images.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my goal. The goal is to have the four tiles on single line and all captions, images and tiles aligned.

Comment: Use Flexbox on the .container class like this                                                '.container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

Answer (score 0):

Use these classes for the tile-topup.
 - d-flex
 - flex-column
 - align-items-center

Doing so, the `img` and `h4` are aligned horizontally in the center. use `justify-content-center` Should you want to align them vertically in the center too. Moreover, you need to remove the  `display` property of the `tile-topup` selector since you use `d-flex`. If you do not want to resize the images, remove the `height` and `width` too.

---

You may use `d-flex` for the `container` too.